# Editing a file using search string in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I am having difficulties in writing a powershell/batch script which needs to search a string in the input file, copy the content of line to next line and replace the string by another string.

For example if my file has following content

```
James is awesome.

Ryan is handsome.

Henry is a bad boy.

Jim is studious
```

And output should look like when script is called with inputs `"***Henry***"` & `"***Glenn***"`

```
James is awesome.

Ryan is handsome.

***Henry*** is a bad boy.

***Glenn*** is a bad boy.

Jim is studious
```

Comment: Would a bash solution be acceptable? This would be relatively easy with sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function that will find word in a line, if found duplicate the line with new word.

```
Function ReplaceAndDuplicate([string[]]$drseus, $thing1, $thing2) {
  $drseus | % { 
    $_
    if ($_ -match $thing1) {
      $_ -replace $thing1, $thing2
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ReplaceAndDuplicate (Get-Content C:\temp\file.txt) "Henry" "Glenn"
```

**And output looks like**

```
James is awesome.
Ryan is handsome.
Henry is a bad boy.
Glenn is a bad boy.
Jim is studious
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for helping out. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for helping out. This is exactly what I was looking for. But output file size is way bigger (more than twice), even if it adds a single line. Though its not a big problem  but any idea how can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$sel = Select-String -Path "FilePath" -Pattern "Henry"
If ($sel -ne $null) {
  $str = Select-String -Path "FilePath" -Pattern "^(Henry).*"
  $str = $str -replace "Henry", ""
  (Get-Content "FilePath") | Foreach {
        $_
        if ($_ -match "Henry")  {
            "`nJim $($str)"
        }
    } | Set-Content "FilePath"
}
```

Comment: This is also working, With some tweaking I was able to get the result.

Comment: Which one is better? You have to accept either @Jawad or my answer (which is better) by clicking the tick mark. Thank you for being helped.

Comment: Both are correct, its just the other solution is closer to the solution. Thanks a lot for helping.